# discord.js v13: how to make a role with the highest available position

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to do a mute command where the bot creates a role and puts it in the **highest** position it can.

Here's my code:

```
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("Eu não tenho perm: `MANAGE_ROLES`");

    let rolecreate = message.guild.roles.create({ name: "", permissions: [], reason: "" }).then((create) => message.member.roles.add(create));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a role as high as the bot's highest role, because after the role is created, the bot's highest role shifts up, and you cannot create a role higher than your own highest role. You can set this with the `position` option:

```js
let rolecreate = message.guild.roles.create({ 
  name: "", 
  permissions: [], 
  reason: "", 
  position: msg.guild.me.roles.highest.position 
})
.then(/*... */);
```